# Multiple field validation with Spring boot ConstraintValidator is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I'm trying to validate multiple fields using spring boot constraintValidator. But it doesn't buzz with no error in it.

Can someone please help me find it out..

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestBody Greeting greeting) {
        System.out.println(greeting);
        return greeting;
    }
```

**Bean thats needs to be validated**

```
@GreetingAnnotation
public class Greeting {
    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

**Annotation**

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = GreetingValidator.class)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GreetingAnnotation {
    String message() default "Field is required";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

**Validator**

```
public class GreetingValidator implements ConstraintValidator<GreetingAnnotation, Greeting > {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Greeting greeting, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return greeting.getId() >=0 && greeting.getContent().length() >=100; // Never gets called
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is just a sample stub for validating an object

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Add "@Component" annotation to GreetingValidator class. 2) Add "@Valid" to parameter "greeting": "@RequestBody @Valid Greeting greeting"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @Validated at your controller level ?

If Not they add it. It will work.